# Create laravel api with page and limit results

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-api

I want to create an api with limit and page number, I am trying to use the api to load more data on scroll in my app.

Question 1: How can I limit the result, per each page.

For example
`https://placewave.com/allusers?results=10&page=2`

The URL above the `page=2` show the second page with `results=10` 10 fetch result for page 2, same thing for page 3 with 10 result.

**My Code**

```
public function allUser(Request $request)
{
    $pageno = $request->pageno;
    return Users::where('active', 'online')
        ->limit(10)->offset($pageno)
        ->get();
}
```

Comment: Instead of `->limit()->offset()->get()`, you _should_ just be able to do `->paginate($request->input('results'))`. Have you checked the documentation for Laravel's pagination? https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination#basic-usage. Using `->paginate()` and having `&page=X` in the URL will automatically do the correct `limit/offset`.

Comment: if I add the paginate `->paginate($request->input('results'))` with I have done before,  how will I indicate the number of `limit` result, so I can fetch the api like this `https://placewave.com/allusers?results=10&page=2`

Comment: Laravel's pagination does that by default. If `results` is the number of records per page, then passing that as the argument to `->paginate()` should work. For example, if you did `paginate(10)`, then on page 1, it's `limit 10 offset 0`. On page 2, `limit 10 offset 10`, page 3, `limit 10 offset 20`, etc etc. Full code would be `Users::where('active', 'online')->paginate($request->input('results'))` (or `$request->results` as a shorthand for `$request->input('results')`; whatever preference)

Comment: So the new code will now look like this:     
`public function allUser(Request $request) {
    return Users::where('active', 'online')
     ->paginate($request->input('results'));
}`

Comment: Without the weird spacing, yes 

Comment: Oh you'll probably want to provide a default number of results per page as well, incase it's missing: `->paginate($request->input('results', 10))`, and maybe some validation to avoid things like `?results=not-a-number`, etc, but that's extra stuff you'll want to handle eventually.

Comment: Thanks Tim I will try it, but since the limit is define am I the re-write the url from `https://placewave.com/allusers?results=10&page=2` to `https://placewave.com/allusers?page=2`

Comment: The URL will hopefully still include the limit, what I was saying with that comment is that if the `?results=X` is removed or tampered with, **you** need to account for that and handle appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel's Pagination already handles `limit` and `offset` by passing the number of records you'd like per-page, and by examining the `page=X` query string parameter. So, you can rewrite your code as follows:

```php
public function allUser(Request $request) {
  return Users::where('active', 'online')->paginate($request->input('results', 10));
}
```

You'll likely want to provide some validation too, to prevent bad actors from messing with your `results` parameter:

```php
public function allUser(Request $request) {
  $perPage = $request->input('results', 10);
  if (!is_numeric($perPage)) {
    $perPage = 10;
  }

  return Users::where('active', 'online')->paginate($perPage);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
->paginate($request->get('results', 10))
```

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: @TimLewis I think you misunderstood my answer.
my answer: retrieve the value of the **results** parameter if it does not exist, use **10** as the default value

Comment: if the question is to get limit value from params, this code works
```
return Users::where('active', 'online')->paginate($request->get('results'), 10);
```

Comment: ... I upvote your answer 